# Select quality profile from Sonar-project.properties file for sonarcloud scan

Tags: sonarqube, devops, sonarcloud, devsecops

I have created a custom quality profile from sonarcloud console. 
I am able to make it default from UI and do the sonarcloud scans for that.
Now, for my use-case: I want to do this from sonar-project.properties file so that I can use different quality profiles for different environments without intervention from the console.
I want to do something like: sonar.qualityprofile.python="custom-profile".
Thanks in advance.